# SQLite SELECT statement for column name where column has a value

Tags: mysql, sqlite, fmdb

What SQLite statement do I need to get the column name WHERE there is a value?

```
COLUMN NAME:   ALPHA BRAVO CHARLIE DELTA ECHO

ROW VALUE:        0    1      0      1     1
```

All I want in my return is: Bravo, Delta, Echo.

Answer (score 2):

Your request is not entirely clear, but you *appear* to be asking for a `SELECT` statement that will return not data but rather columns names, and not a predictable number of values but rather a number values that depend on the data in the table.

For instance,

```
A B C D E
0 1 0 1 1
```

would return (B,D,E) whereas

```
A B C D E
1 0 1 0 0
```

would return (A, C).

If that's what you're asking, this is not something that SQL does.  SQL retrieves data *from* the table and an SQL result set always has the same number of columns per row.

To accomplish your goal, you would have to retrieve all columns that *might* have a value in the table and then, in your program code, check for the value in each column and accrue a list of column names that had values.

Also, consider what happens when there is more than one row to examine and the distribution of values differ.  In other words, what's the expected result if the data looks like this:

```
A B C D E
- - - - -
0 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 0
```

[Also, note that *all* the columns in your example have values, some 0, some 1.  What you really want is a list of column names where the column contains a value of 1.]

Finally, consider that your inability to easily get the results you need from your data might indicate a flaw in the data model you're using.  For instance, if you were to structure your data like this:

```
 TagName   TagValue
 -------   --------
 Alpha      0
 Bravo      1
 Charlie    0
 Delta      1
 Echo       1
```

you could then obtain your results with `SELECT TagName FROM Tags WHERE TagValue = 1`.

Furthermore, if 0 and 1 are really the only two possible values (indicating boolean "presence" or "absence" of the tag) then you could remove the TagValue column and the rows for `Alpha` and `Charlie` entirely (you'd `INSERT` a row into the table to add tag and `DELETE` a row to remove it).

A design along these lines seems to model your data more accurately and allows you to entire new tags to the system without having to issue an `ALTER TABLE` command.

Answer (score -1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1407e/1

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF(ALPHA,'ALPHA,',''),
             IF(BRAVO,'BRAVO,',''),
             IF(CHARLIE,'CHARLIE,',''),
             IF(DELTA,'DELTA,',''),
             IF(ECHO,'ECHO','')) 
FROM table1
```